# Returning a value from function

Tags: java, function, stack, return-value, return

How does returning a value from a function internally works ?

See this example..

[image]

Comment: @whirlWind : Hey...That's not my homework.I just wanted to try  something new.I hope this is allowed here.

Comment: It could be homework.  If so, they're not using a very good book: "system" is not capitalized, and the entire line would cause an "unreachable statement" error.

Comment: Hey All...I know there might be some mistakes..But ,for ur kind information, I have just given a reference code..This is not an actual compiled code...

Comment: Hey this is not exactly a Java question.
Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: -1 Bad example. Make sure to include *actual text* in questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JVM uses a value stack to hold values, and the stack is shared across all method calls on that thread.  Normally, when a non-void method returns, the return value is pushed on the stack, and the caller pops it off the stack and either uses it or discards it.

Answer (score 2):

#### [JLS 14.17 The `return` Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.17)

> [...] A `return` statement with no *Expression* **attempts** to transfer control to the invoker of the method or constructor that contains it.
>
> [...] A `return` statement with an *Expression* **attempts** to transfer control to the invoker of the method that contains it; the value of the *Expression* becomes the value of the method invocation.
>
> [...] It can be seen, then, that a return statement always completes abruptly.

The abrupt completion *does* mean that any following statements will not be executed, and this can in fact lead to compile-time error in some cases ([JLS 14.21 Unreachable Statements](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.21))

```
void unreachable() {
   return;
   System.out.println("Bye!"); // DOESN'T COMPILE! Unreachable code!
}
```

Continuing on...

> The preceding descriptions say "**attempts** to transfer control" rather than just "transfers control" because if there are any `try` statements [...] then any `finally` clauses [...] will be executed [...] Abrupt completion of a `finally` clause can disrupt the transfer of control initiated by a `return` statement.

This means that the following function will `return -1` instead of `0`.

```
int tryReturn() {
   try {
      return 0;
   } finally {
      return -1;
   }
}
```

In the absence of `try-finally`, though, the control will be immediately transferred, and the *Expression* value, if any, will be passed on to the caller.